# Why do I get a lot of "Not an answer" flags disputed recently?

Tags: discussion

No doubt there are always different opinions on flags if they either suit to the post, a different should be set or none should be set completely. But in the past few days I encountered a significant higher disputing rate than normal, I refer to *Not an answer* flags.

I flagged all these answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358568/8283469), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360028/8283469), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379544/8283469), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49381101/8283469) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360205/8283469). All those are just a few examples about the past few days, even though all of them are just from today and not even the only ones. All these answers are just *code only answers* or *link only answers*.

According to this post: [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277)

> Currently, the following scenarios result in a flag being disputed: [...]
>
> A "not an answer" or "very low quality" flag kicks the post into the Low Quality Posts review queue but the final result of the review was "Looks OK".

So the cause for those flags getting disputed is that other people think that I have set a wrong flag and that the post is fine. But I am confused, what do I overlook that makes those answers valid?

Comment: Those are all answers though they may not be correct or high quality.

Comment: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: Looking at them, I'd say you should have just downvoted them.

Comment: Code blocks _are_ answers. Probably worthy of a DV, but they attempt to answer the question. The one with the hyperlink was borderline, but we typically favor on the side of "it's an answer" since it did say: `You can use  Context.registerReceiver()`.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, now I am about to understand all of you guys opinion/explaination.

Comment: @Vega Of course.  It's suggesting a solution to the problem.  I have no idea if it's correct, or if more information is necessary in that situation, but it's *an answer*.

Comment: @Vega I see only a comment as well. Why would the comment section exist if not this reply of the answerer belongs there?

Comment: @Vega & L. Guthardt Comments aren't for short answers.  Comments are there to attempt to improve the post they are commenting on, by requesting clarification, pointing out a problem, suggesting a change that would improve that post, etc.  That answer is *suggesting an answer to the question asked*, not describing how the question can be improved, and as such should be posted as an answer, and not a comment, regardless of how long or short it is.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you about all the other usage of the comment section. But if you allow such short answers, questions can be spammed with short and low quality answers to make the post just completely messy, but this would still suit in the SO guidelines. It's quite confusing to me, since SO has already the problem of the low quality,... post flood.

Comment: @L.Guthardt If you feel that an answer to that question requires more information that that answer contains, then feel free to downvote it and point out what information is missing from that answer that you feel is necessary for it to be complete.  Those are the tools that are given to you for dealing with answers that you feel are missing information.  We don't *want* people posting short answers as comments.  Again, comments (on the question) are there to improve the question, not for short answers.  It's a [small] *problem* when people are posting answers as comments

Comment: It may be an answer, but it is not a good answer. Such low effort answers should be downvoted because they don't explain anything.

Comment: Ok, thank you once again @Servy. Now I finally understood you completely and will act according to that model.

Comment: @yivi I was quite happy once I just saw that you left a comment under each *low quality answer* I posted. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: [Auto-comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) are your friends.

Comment: @yivi You are my hero. I always wondered if people do really rewrite all these *defaults comments* on low quality posts, etc. with those different suggestions about SO's help pages. Now I am enlightened.

Comment: @yivi Is there some meta post about such "tools" that gives users like me an overview about the stuff that makes interactions with reviewing, etc. easier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of those are non-answers.  They're all answers to the question.  You might think that they're *low quality* answers.  If so, feel free to downvote them.

The NAA flag is not for answers that you don't like, it's for posts that *aren't even an attempted answers*.

Posting a bunch of code is an attempt to answer the question.  It's rarely a *good answer*, but it is *an answer*.

The one post you linked that contained a link does indeed contain a link, but *even if you remove the link* there is still an answer there.   You might think that it's incomplete, or not sufficiently detailed, or wrong, or whatever, but *it's an answer*, even when never actually visiting the link.

Comment: *If so, feel free to downvote them.* worth noting that none of those answers had a down vote on them at the time of posting this.

Comment: Hmm ok, I got that. But then I am still quite confused. I get here and there this *test* where I flag or what so ever a post in a review queue and I get the message that this post has already been removed and I passed, ... and so on. (You all know what I mean) And then there is the explaination for the already removal that this was not an answer. Furthermore there are quite often people who comment those answers and tell them that this *code only answer* does not provide an answer.

Comment: @L.Guthardt If another post was deleted because it's a code only answer then *that was wrong* and it's a problem.  The system of course isn't perfect, some people to erroneously try to delete actual answers even though they know that they are answers, and the system doesn't alway succeed in stopping them.  Lots of people will comment to say that a code only answer is a *bad* answer, or perhaps that it doesn't *succeed* in answering.  If they comment to say that it's not an answer at all, or that it merits deletion on that grounds, then you now know that they're wrong, and you can correct them.

Comment: @Servy Ok, thank your for your time and explaination. I will try to follow that model.

Answer (score 8):

> So the cause for those flags getting disputed is that other people think that I have set a wrong flag and that the post is fine. But I am confused, what do I overlook that makes those answers valid?

The other answers address your underlying question, but I feel the need to clarify this bit just for your peace of mind: **reviewers don't know that you flagged.** Posts can enter the queues for multiple reasons: heuristics, Not an Answer flags, Very Low Quality flags... And reviewers are only asked to judge whether or not the answer is sufficiently relevant to remain on the site.

[image: screenshot of guidance text in LQ review]

Often, this is a judgement call: this is why flags are *disputed* rather than declined. But it is always based on the reviewers' evaluation of the post itself; they do not and cannot see that it was flagged or who raised the flag.

Comment: Thank you, that you took as well some time to explain me the process. Very good information and I am quite thankful for the clarification.

Comment: In the help part for reviewing Low Quality Posts of which you posted a screenshot, would it be a good idea to change "Looks OK if nothing is wrong with this answer" to something like "Looks OK if this answer isn't bad enough for deletion"? "Looks OK" is the correct for code-only answers, but there is something wrong with code-only answers. Just not enough to delete them.

Comment: Folks tend to err on the side of "Looks OK" already, @Donald. We altered that from the original "Looks Good" to try to set a good balance - truth is, an awful lot of these "code-only" answers could use a bit of gentle encouragement even if they're not worth being deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Even though those are poor answers and definitely need improving, they still provide an "answer" to the question, NAA flags are used when something is posted as an answer that doesn't even attempt to provide an answer like "Have you found a solution yet?" or "@Someone how do I implement the answer in my code?"

I looked at all of those answers in the links you provided and they would all pass the test of not being NAA but they would still personally require editing from the answer to improve the answer.

Comment: I was quite happy once I just saw that you left a comment under each *low quality answer* I posted. Thank you for your effort.